# What is wrong with this PHP code to print a list of user's friends who also use the app?

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-fql

I am quite new to PHP so this may be a stupid question. I have tried many different ways to get this to work but without success. I am trying to make a list of the app user's friends who also use the app but no values are printed. There is common app users when I test it as I have tested the [FQL](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.query) query on Facebook's Graph API tool with success. I already have $user_profile declared at the start of the file to the Graph API /me. I redeclared it when I had a new use for the variable but it won't work when I try to get the user's friends who use the app.  The code is below:

```
<?php
echo $user_profile['name'] . " is connected.";

echo "<ul>";

$user_profile = $facebook->api('/fql?q=SELECT name, uid FROM user WHERE is_app_user=$appId and uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())');

foreach ($user_profile["data"] as $value) {
    $uid = $value["uid"];
    $name = $value["name"];
    echo "<li>" . $name . ": " . $uid . ".</li>";
}

echo "</ul>";
?>
```

The code is connected to the PHP SDK and the session has been set up correctly. The current user is said to be connected due to the line:

```
echo $user_profile['name'] . " is connected.";
```

Any help to why this is not working would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You're calling it before you declare `$user_profile = $facebook...`. Put it after that line.

Comment: I already have $user_profile declared at the start of the document to the Graph API /me. I redeclared it when I had a new use for the variable but it won't work when I try to get the user's friends who use the app.

Comment: So you're overwriting $user_profile?  After $user_profile = $facebook type in `print_r($user_profile);` and let us know what that says.

Comment: Nothing is displayed. I tried creating a new variable for the second api call but it still does not work. Do I have to decode JSON or something like that do you think? Thanks.

Comment: If nothing is being displayed, then there's nothing to json_decode().  Turn on error_reporting() and see what errors show up.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
<?php


  echo "<ul>";

  $user_profile = $facebook->api('/fql?q=SELECT name, uid FROM user WHERE 
  is_app_user=$appId and uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())');

  echo $user_profile['name'] . " is connected.";

  foreach ($user_profile["data"] as $value) {
     $uid = $value["uid"];
     $name = $value["name"];
     echo "<li>" . $name . ": " . $uid . ".</li>";
 }

 echo "</ul>";
?>
```